# Give project-based access to items in DynamoDB using Cognito and IAM

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-cognito, amazon-iam

I use AWS Cognito as our user pool, and AWS DynamoDB for our data.

I would like to have fine-grained control over DynamoDB items (rows), on a per-user basis.
I am aware of strategies using user_id or tenant_id as the primary key, but these don't seem like they would work for my application.

The items in my database are project-based - so the partition keys are the project codes, e.g. '#PR001', '#PR002', '#PR003'.
I have different groups of users (roles) with different permissions, i.e. viewers who can read-only, editors who can edit some of the data, and super-editors who can edit all of the data.
The projects that each user has access to is not simply grouped by tenancy. For example (pseudo-code):

```
user_1 = {
    role: "viewer",
    projects: ["#PR001","#PR003","#PR005"]
}
user_2 = {
    role: "editor",
    projects: ["#PR002","#PR003"]
}
user_3 = {
    role: "super-editor",
    projects: ["#PR001","#PR005"]
}
```

What is the simplest approach to giving users the right type of access to only the projects they are assigned to? Would it be possible to have a item in my DDB that stores the access list for projects? Would that be secure?

NB. My user pool is small at the moment so it is not a big problem if there are some manual steps involved.

Comment: Did you investigate using DynamoDB [fine-grained access control](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/specifying-conditions.html) policies? One challenge is that you'd probably need to create multiple Cognito user groups, each with an IAM role allowing access to DynamoDB items for a specific project and then assign users to multiple groups, as needed. I know you can assign a Cognito user to multiple groups but haven't validated this. You can't leverage a per-user project list stored in DynamoDB itself unless you write custom app server code for authorization imo.

Comment: Yes I did, it seems like an easy option, however, it does not really scale. So I could make groups for each combination of project + role, i.e. 'project001_editor', 'project001_viewer', 'project002_editor', etc. Then assign each user to each appropriate group. However, Cognito has a 100 group limit per user, so that would also be the limit for the number of projects per user.

Comment: Instead of using group membership and managing group policies, take a look at custom Lambda authorizer options (example [here](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/building-fine-grained-authorization-using-amazon-cognito-api-gateway-and-iam/) where Lambda returns a custom policy and optional context to API Gateway). Also, be aware of [Amazon Verified Permissions](https://aws.amazon.com/verified-permissions/), though it's not yet GA.

Answer (score 1):

As the comments mention, a external fine-grained permissions solution, like [Amazon Verified Permissions](https://aws.amazon.com/verified-permissions/) when generally available may offer the most flexibility.

You also can use a feature of DynamoDB to solve this.  From https://www.alexdebrie.com/posts/dynamodb-transactions/#access-control

> A third use case for transactions is in an authorization or access control setting.

Let's assume:

- users are in `USER_TABLE_NAME` with `user` as the PK, `role` as the SK, and `projects` is a String Set of the projects related to that role.
- projects are in `PROJECT_TABLE_NAME` with `project` as PK as `status` is green|yellow|red

The prototype (no error checks) TypeScript code below can be called via `update_project("user_2", "#PR002", "red");` to update project "#PR002" to status "red" for "user_2".

The `ConditionCheck` in the transaction checks the `user` is an "editor" and the `project` is in the list of their projects.  Only if that succeeds does the `Update` execute.  See Amazon DynamoDB Developer Guide [Managing complex workflows with DynamoDB transactions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/transactions.html) for full details.

```
const update_project = async function (
  user: string,
  project: string,
  status: "green" | "yellow" | "red"
) {
  const ddbResponse = await ddbClient.send(
    new TransactWriteItemsCommand({
      TransactItems: [
        {
          ConditionCheck: {
            TableName: USER_TABLE_NAME,
            Key: {
              user: { S: user },
              role: { S: "editor" },
            },
            ConditionExpression: "contains(projects, :project)",
            ExpressionAttributeValues: {
              ":project": { S: project },
            },
          },
        },
        {
          Update: {
            TableName: PROJECT_TABLE_NAME,
            Key: {
              project: { S: project },
            },
            UpdateExpression: "SET #S = :status",
            ExpressionAttributeNames: {
              "#S": "status",
            },
            ExpressionAttributeValues: {
              ":status": { S: status },
            },
          },
        },
      ],
    })
  );
};
```

When called using "user_1" it will fail with:

> TransactionCanceledException: Transaction cancelled, please refer cancellation reasons for specific reasons [ConditionalCheckFailed, None]

You will need to update with your specific rules, allowing viewer to GetItem and editor to only update your specific fields.